# why getting syntax error when implementing seekbar change listener?

Tags: android, actionlistener, onchange, seekbar

I'm using a seekbar in my android app and when implementing it's onChangeListener it gives me syntax errors :

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error on token "setOnSeekBarChangeListener", = expected after 
     this token
    - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
```

although I'm taking the changeListener code from a ready made seekbar project which by the way works perfectly with me.

here's the seekbar code:

```
SeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener(){
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekar, int progress, boolean fromUser){
        seekbarPercent.setText(progress + "%");
    }

    });
```

Comment: can you post part of the code above to it?

Comment: post your whole code of Activity

Comment: sry gays, my bad . were declaring it out of the method :D

Comment: Thats why told you to post your whole code.

Comment: @PiyushGupta yes, i thinked about that because of your comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import OnSeekBarChangeListener properly...

```
seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```